# How to save a trained model from a Vertex AI custom training to Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-artifact-registry, custom-training

The following Python code generates a trained model called `wine_mdl`:

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm
import logging

logging.info('Loading a Scikit-learn toy dataset')
wine_df=datasets.load_wine(as_frame=True)

logging.info('Model training')
wine_mdl=svm.SVC(probability=True)
wine_mdl.fit(X=wine_df.data, y=wine_df.target)

# logging.info('Saving the trained model')
```

I want to run a custom job on Vertex AI Training:

- without managed dataset
- a scikit-learn pre-built container
- a code packaged according to the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container)
- a Google Storage output directory `gs://my-bucket-for-vertexai/my-output-directory`
  [image: Vertex AI Training container configuration]

Which line(s) of code could I add to the above Python code to export the trained model to the dedicated Google Storage repository ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the environment variable `AIP_MODEL_DIR` to write your model to the output directory that you defined in the job according [to this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/code-requirements#environment-variables). Here's an example taken from [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/exporting-model-artifacts#pickle_1).

```
import os
import pickle

from google.cloud import storage
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(data, target)

artifact_filename = 'model.pkl'

# Save model artifact to local filesystem (doesn't persist)
local_path = artifact_filename
with open(local_path, 'wb') as model_file:
  pickle.dump(classifier, model_file)

# Upload model artifact to Cloud Storage
model_directory = os.environ['AIP_MODEL_DIR']
storage_path = os.path.join(model_directory, artifact_filename)
blob = storage.blob.Blob.from_string(storage_path, client=storage.Client())
blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)
```

Make sure to give the right name to your model. `model.pkl` or `model.joblib` is expected if you're using scikit-learn. [Read more here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/exporting-model-artifacts).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35577380)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my answer with the relevant code, hope it's better now. Let me know if there's anything else I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? You will need to install [Vertex AI SDK for Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest#models):

To upload a model:

```
model = aiplatform.Model.upload( display_name='my-model', artifact_uri="gs://python/to/my/model/dir", serving_container_image_uri="us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/prediction/tf2-cpu.2-2:latest", )
```

Comment: After trying your command, the job returned the following error message: _google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"_

Comment: Can you try the "before you begin" section here specially step 3 onwards: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/client-libraries#before_you_begin